# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip.commands'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, virtualenv

I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "setup.py", line 8, in <module>
from pip.commands import WheelCommand
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip.commands'
```

While I have python (screenshot attached)

Python 3.6.3 :: Anaconda, Inc.

pip 18.1

wheel 0.32.2

Any suggestion will be highly appreciable[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a little problem with you `import` in `setup.py` file. you should write like this:

```
from pip._internal.commands import WheelCommand
```

it is because you can only import `1._vendor` and `2._internal` from pip.

Comment: thanks @mehrdad-pedramfar , that worked. just one more thing , there seems a typo . It should be from pip._internal.commands import WheelCommand